# Dropdown value not being retained

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown which gets its value from a model and is first populated. On click of that dropdown, I populate other values using AJAX. I am able to populate the dropdown but once I select an option from the dropdown, it gets reset to first value in the dropdown. What I want is the dropdown to populate once on click and then function like a normal dropdown. How do I put a condition for it?

This is the code for initially setting the dropdown value with the defined value 'field.Value'

```
ddlValue = "<option value="+field.Value+ " selected='selected'>" + field.Value+"</option>";

<td><select id='@String.Format("selValue{0}", field.Field)' class='ddlValue'>@Html.Raw(ddlValue)</select></td>
```

And this is the AJAX function which populates it.

```
$('body').on('click', '.ddlValue', function () {
    var target = event.target.id;
    var rowId = $('#' + target).closest("tr").prop("id");
    var field = $('#' + rowId).find(".fieldvalue").html();

        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            url: '@Url.Action("PopulateDropdown", "AdvancedSearch")',
            type: "POST",
            data: { Field: field }
        }).done(function (data) {

            var listb = $('#' + target);
            listb.empty();

            $.each(data.value, function (index, value) {
                listb.append($('<option>', {
                    value: value,
                    text: value
                }, '<option/>'))
            });

        });

});
```

Comment: Are you trying to get the dropdown to populate itself?

Comment: @FailedUnitTest I populate the dropdown with only one value. When someone cliscks on the dropdown, I am using on click function to populate the rest.

Comment: The behavior described seemed reasonable given the code provided.  Every time you click the dropdown, the dropdown clicked will be emptied and repopulated.  Is that not what you want?

Comment: Yes @tpdietz is correct, the drop-down is repopulated every time you click an option as well, causing the first value to always be chosen. I personally don't like the idea of populating a drop-down on click; why do you populate it on click, what are you achieving by this? Why not populate all values from the start?

Comment: @tpdietz I understand that the dropdown gets repopulated on click. What I want is the dropdown populates once and then I do not want the dropdown to call the function.

Comment: @tpdietz I have modified the question a little, think it makes my question more clear.

Comment: @FailedUnitTest I have modified the question a little, think it makes my question more clear.

Comment: I see you are using ASP.NET MVC, why not populate the dropdown from razor view?

Comment: I agree with @FailedUnitTest.  Although there is a solution to your problem, I think populating a drop down on click with an ajax is a little sketchy.  What happens if it takes 1 second to receive the response?  The user may get confused.  At any rate, I wish you the best of luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the ajax population to happen only once, you need to remove the event listener after it has occurred.  Something like so:

```
$('.ddlValue').on('click', function () {

    $(this).off('click'); //This removes the event after it has happened once.

    var target = event.target.id;
    var rowId = $('#' + target).closest("tr").prop("id");
    var field = $('#' + rowId).find(".fieldvalue").html();

    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        url: '@Url.Action("PopulateDropdown", "AdvancedSearch")',
        type: "POST",
        data: { Field: field }
    }).done(function (data) {

        var listb = $('#' + target);
        listb.empty();

        $.each(data.value, function (index, value) {
            listb.append($('<option>', {
                value: value,
                text: value
            }, '<option/>'))
        });

    });

});
```

Please note, the follow will **not** work:

```
$('body').on('click', '.ddlValue', function () {
    $(this).off('click');
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a silly way of doing this. You could do the same operation on loan without having any interaction with the user to populate the dropdown.

That being said to fix your solution simply add a global variable

```
$first = true
$('body').on('click', '.ddlValue', function () {
   if($first) {
      $first = false
      var target = event.target.id;
      var rowId = $('#' + target).closest("tr").prop("id");
      var field = $('#' + rowId).find(".fieldvalue").html();
      $.ajax({
         cache: false,
         url: '@Url.Action("PopulateDropdown", "AdvancedSearch")',
         type: "POST",
         data: { Field: field }
      }).done(function (data) {
         var listb = $('#' + target);
         listb.empty();
         $.each(data.value, function (index, value) {
         listb.append($('<option>', {
           value: value,
           text: value
         }, '<option/>'))
       });
     }
   });
});
```

Comment: I believe this type of solution will get complicated if there are several elements that match $('.ddlValue'), as your boolean flag will be stale.

Comment: I have the same comment to make. Does not work when there are multiple fields with class ddlValue.

Comment: "I have a dropdown which gets its value from a model and is first populated. On click of that dropdown" switch it to an id then if its singular.